# How to pass parameters like auth ,headers, verify ,stream when using downloader object of pypdl module to download data from url parallely

Tags: python

```
from pypdl import Downloader

dl = Downloader()
dl. start(url , filepath)
```

Here since I am not able to give the auth ,headers details. I am unable to connect with the source and it gives the connection error

Answer (score 2):

I am the maintainer of pypdl, it didn't have any option to add header but now i have added that option (pypdl 0.0.8). now you can set custom headers via setting the `header` (dict) attribute of `Downloader`

```
from pypdl import Downloader

def main():
    # create a new downloader object
    dl = Downloader()

    # Use custom headers to set user-agent
    dl.headers = {User-Agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}

    # start the download
    dl.start(
        url='https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin',
        filepath='100MB.bin')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

make sure to not set any `range header` if you are using multithread downloading

Comment: Thank you Jishnu for the information and updates